# Arrange a few element in ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I am getting some data for Array and that I am iterating in view through ngFor loop. I have one row and I used col-lg-3 do display 4 data in each row.if I am getting 10 datas from array then 8 datas will arrange automatically in two rows but when last 2 data comes to third row it is displaying in left side. I want that last 2 data to be in center of the row.

I have used already (margin: 0 auto) in css Last two datas are moved little bit but not aligning at the center.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let item of proprtyName">
        <div class="top-left"><img src="assets/img/bookmark_icon/group-8-copy.png"></div>
        <div class="top-right1">
            <img src="assets/img/rank_icon/group.png" style="width: 60px;
                height: 60px;">
            <p style="margin-top:-40px;">8/10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron text-center cardtable1">
            <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
            <h5>&#8377; 1.4 Cr</h5>
            <img src = "http://182.76.7.2:8080/Adnoc/image/bitmap2.png" style="width: 100px;
                height: 100px;"> 
            <table>
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        <p>5000 Sq</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>3 and 4 BHK</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>5000 Sq</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>5000 Sq</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Rate : 5000 mm</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-left"><button class="btn btn-default btnpro" type="submit"><span>View Properties</span></button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an array

```
    this.proprtyName = [
       {id: 1, name: "Gala Imperia"},
       {id: 2, name: "Gala Imperia 1"},
       {id: 3, name: "Gala Imperia 2"},
       {id: 4, name: "Gala Imperia 3"},
       {id: 5, name: "Gala Imperia 4"},
       {id: 6, name: "Gala Imperia 5"},
       {id: 7, name: "Gala Imperia 6"},
       {id: 8, name: "Gala Imperia 7"},
       {id: 9, name: "Gala Imperia 8"},
       {id: 10, name: "Gala Imperia 9"}
    ];
  }
```

expecting output is:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This will centralise whatever columns you have for each row.

`<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">`